# Print each process in OPL

Tags: printing, cplex, opl

I'm a college student in Taiwan and I'm doing a research about "how much wind turbines and solar photovoltaic panels should be installed to satisfy the require of minimum energy penetration rate in a semiconductor factory".

My professor hope I can display each variable in each period, but I don't know what code I should write.
Maybe there will be "execute" and "writeln" in my code? But there is nothing happened.

The following is my brief code:

```
{string} product = ...;
range time = 1..2;
{string} GreenPower = ...;
string NonGreenPower = ...；

dvar float InPut[product][time]; //In t period, amount of input of products
dvar float working[product][time]; //In t period, amount of working of products
dvar float OutPut[product][time]; //In t period, amount of output of products
```

So, I want to see the change in IntPut in each time, how to do it.

Thanks for your reading and tolerating my grammatical or spelling mistakes QQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print the solution to a console, you can use a post-processing block. A post-processing block is implemented by putting an `execute` block *after* the constraint specification (after the `subject to` block).

A post-processing block to print variables could look like this (untested code):

```
execute {
  for (var p in product) {
    for (var t in time) {
      writeln(p + ", " + t + ": " + InPut[p][t] + ", " + working[p][t] + ", " + OutPut[p][t]);
    }
  }
}
```

Many of the examples shipped with CPLEX use post processing to display solutions to the console. You can look through them to learn what can be done in post processing and what are different ways to visualize solutions in the console.